# Inserting label's values from SugarCrm document (sp_ve.js) into some table in mysql

Tags: json, pentaho, sugarcrm

I am using a software powered by SugarCRM. The reports I show are not very good so I decided to user Pentaho BI Suite. I already made all the business analitycs stuff (cubes, reports, saiku report, etc..), but I am having an issue, in SugarCRM database, the label's values of some dropdownlist (for example), are not storaged. Instead they are written in a .JS file y the sugar directory called `sp_ve.js` like this :

```
 SUGAR.language.SetLanguage('app_string',[JSON OBJECT WITH THE LABELS VALUES]) ;
 SUGAR.language.SetLanguage('app_list_strings',[JSON OBJECT WITH LABEL VALUES]);
```

Now, is there any way to insert those objects into tables, so I can use it in my OLAP solution in pentaho?, HOW? . If yes, how can I make this process work automatically, every time my users add new labels.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all the dropdowns, text labels, etc. actually stored in `<lang_key>.lang.php` files under `<sugar_root>/include/language/` and `<sugar_root>/custom/include/language/` directories. And only then those labels become accessible with JavaScript used in SugarCRM UI. See [this page](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework/Language/Labels_and_Lists) for more information.

For similar situation of preparing SugarCRM database for analyzing with Tableau Desktop Professional I decided to use the following approach.

At the beginning all the dictionaries/mappings needed in files mentioned above were extracted into separate CSV files. You can do it with text editor of your choice using find/replace. Then those CSV files were imported into SugarCRM database as new tables - one table for each list. After that I used database view to join "data" table with "label map" table and used that view as a source for my analytical needs. Yes, it's not so elegant and dynamic solution. Moreover it needs a little hand work. But it solves the issue.